# Calling functions on the parent "class" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having an issue with passing parameters to closures within my view components. If I do the below I get an error telling me `this.updateSelection()` is not a valid function.

```
methods: {
    getSelectedItems() {
        axios.get('api/model/' + this.model.id)
            .then(function(response) => {
                this.updateSelection(response.data.selectedItems);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    },
    updateSelection(selectedItems) {
        this.selectedItems = selectedItems;
    },
}
```

I can make it work using the ECMA 6 syntax:

```
.then(response => {
    this.updateSelection(response.data.selectedItems);
})
```

But I can't work out how I would make the function available to the closure without the ECMA 6 syntax. Something like:

```
.then(function(response) => {
    parent.updateSelection(response.data.selectedItems);
})
```

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key to this issue is understanding the difference between arrow functions and "normal" functions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

I would suggest you don't use ES5 functions when you want to access `this` context. During the build process the transpiler (i.e. babel) will handle translating arrow functions into ES5.

Historically there were several ways of bypassing the problem. One of them was declaring a variable in the closure that would hold the value of the parent's `this`:

```js
var that = this;
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this); // document
  console.log(that); // "this" from the parent scope
});
```

Another way is to use `bind` method:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (function() {
  console.log(this); // "this" from the parent scope
}).bind(this));
```

Which was commonly used i.e. in React until only recently, but people started to switch to arrow functions anyway, so the need decreased significantly.

Comment: Thanks @Uriziel. This is a great answer, well structured and really helps to clarify the issue for me. Much appreciated :)